# Magento 2 - Attributes options value is not showing

Tags: magento2

we're facing a new problem. The values of the product attributes no longer showing in backend, they dissapeared. The values are in database.

The old products still have these options for filtering but are not showing in backend.

[image: magento 2 attributes options]

I've tried all the situations, reindex, clear cache, disable production mode, deploy content, nothing helps.

LATER EDIT:
- i found that if i disable module Magento_Swatches the attributes not showing anymore.

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: `indexer_state` table all are `valid`?

Comment: yes all is green..